# Lotusscript : Opening saved document in edit mode

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I would like to edit/read document which is been just saved, below is the code I am putting but it opens view first document on which the LS agent code is being run. this agent runs on Notes client.

```
Call ReportDoc.Save(1,0)
Call ws.EditDocument(False, ReportDoc, False)
```

I also tried getting univrsal id and tried but same output.

Please assist.

Comment: Where is the code (in a button?) and what code gets executed after those two lines?

Comment: Yes it is in view action button, action button in turn calls agent and agent generates reports and saves it, I need to open the saved document. after this code it is calling exit sub and program gets terminated.

Comment: Are you sure, that ReportDoc is NOT the first documebt in view? Please post your code how you get / create the report document as the error must be there not in the code you posted

Comment: I am putting like 'set NewReportDoc= new notesdocument(thisdb) Set NewAppRTItem = New NotesRichTextItem(NewReportDoc, "NewApplicationsBody" )
 Set RewNewAppRTItem = New NotesRichTextItem(NewReportDoc, "ReassessmentBody" )' here appending contents to RTfield using richtextnevigator and table lastly call NewReportDoc.save(1,0) and call ws.editdocument(false,NewReportDoc,false)

Comment: Have you set Form field?

Answer (score 0):

Probaly `Save()` doesn't work. Notes takes the current selected document in view then for `EditDocument()`.

Change your code to:

```
If ReportDoc.Save(True, False) Then
    Call ws.EditDocument(False, ReportDoc, False)
Else
    MessageBox "Save failed", 48, "Error"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, let me give  a try and get back to you.

Comment: This did not worked, even it does not gives error, but reports get saved and opens up the document of current view where action button in turns runs agent.

Comment: It works well if I remove current views form formula ( where the agent runs from action button) I really don't understand this.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't actually opening the new document?  If there's a form formula, and it's evaluating to a form name that's not the same form that you expect for ReportDoc and doesn't include NewApplicationsBody and ReassessmentBod then you won't see those fields. You'll see the fields that exist on the form formula's form.  And BTW, I noticed that in your code in a comment above, you didn't even set the value for ReportDoc.form.